# MySQL Query is slowing down page load

Tags: php, mysql

I run this query

```
        $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'departments'");
        while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
        {
            $depts = array("Name" => $row1['Name'], "Value" => $row1['Value'], "ID" => $row['CollegeID']);
        }
```

with three other simple queries, one loads data into profile text boxes, and another loads a drop down. Is something wrong with my Query here or my PHP code that could be causing this. It only returns about 51 records. Do you think it could be the server the MySQL server is running on a 2008 Windows Server.

Comment: have you tried just `SELECT * FROM departments` without the quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have many columns in departments table. Try this:

```
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT Name, Value, CollegeID  FROM 'departments'");
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
    {
        $depts = array("Name" => $row1['Name'], "Value" => $row1['Value'], "ID" => $row['CollegeID']);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using the OOP mysqli functions rather than the old mysql versions.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$mysqli->query("SELECT Name, Value, CollegeID  FROM departments");
```

Comment: I also agree with using LIMIT not using * to select data

Answer (score 0):

Never use `*`

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT Name, Value, CollegeID  FROM 'departments'");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
    $depts = array("Name" => $row1['Name'], "Value" => $row1['Value'], "ID" => $row['CollegeID']);
}
```

and use LIMIT

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT Name, Value, CollegeID  FROM 'departments' LIMIT 1");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
    $depts = array("Name" => $row1['Name'], "Value" => $row1['Value'], "ID" => $row['CollegeID']);
}
```

it doesn't matter in your case because you're always overwriting your actual `$depts` variable with new one row